# Does recycle call Startup.Configuration?

Tags: iis, owin

Is the following code called after recycle when hosted in IIS:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(xxx.Startup))]

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, recycling works similary to "Reset", with the difference of first starting a new worker process and then shuting down the old in an attempt to keep the website availible for requests. It also tries to transfer the old requests to new process.

Good Article on this topic: https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/